# Update columns from information of another table using variables with return of multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I'm relatively new to SQL and have been searching for a solution for nearly a week now and wondering whether any expert here could give me some advice please:

For start, I'm using SQL server management tool 2018 for my work. I have two tables X and Y, Table X contains column ID, A, B, C... and table Y contains column ID, Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy etc.

I need update table X , column A=Ax+Ay if Ax>Ay, or A=Ay+Ax if Ax<=Ay, so value in column A will be AxAy or AyAx.

Same with Column B, C etc.

I try to use declare function but it gives error message saying subquery returned more than 1 value, I understand that's probably because the set queries return multiple rows of data.But what's the best way of doing this?

```
declare @column varchar (20), @x varchar (20), @y varchar(20) 
set @column=(select A from TableX);
set @x=(select Ax from TableY) 
set @y=(select Ay from TableY) 
update TableX
set @column=(@y+@x)
from TableX 
inner join TableY
on TableX.ID=TableY.ID 
where @x <= @y
```

Please could you help?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `set @column` isn't valid syntax. You can't update the value of a variable in an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: `A=Ax+Ay` (...) or `A=Ay+Ax`. What is the difference between this 2 sums?

Comment: @Larnu why can't? In general, it is possible to update the variable in the `UPDATE` statement. For example, this works fine: `declare @i int;

update ANY_TABLE
set  @i = 1000

select @i`

Comment: Thanks Nunoq, those are text fields, not numbers. I need to have smaller field to be at the front.

Comment: Thanks Makcnm, what do you think is the best way to update my columns please?

Comment: Ok, true, it's syntax, @МаксимЗолотенко, but it won't update any columns: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e916b7e49fafa6193d60fb5e721966ed)

Comment: @Larnu, *but it won't update any columns* - agree.

Comment: First thank you all for your help. The reason I am using the variables is there are many columns to update, not just three. I thought I could set the column names to `Ax`, `Ay` and `A` for `@X`, `@Y` and `@Column` respectively each time I update one column. Is this possible? If not, would it possible for me to remove `@Column` and just use the actual column name for the column need to be updated, but still use `@x` and `@y` for the variable of `Ax`, `Ay`, `Bx`, `By` etc etc?

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL. Is stored procedure suitable for your task? You can pass column names in the procedure and update the necessary columns.

Comment: Many thanks Makcnm, yes, I tried the 'case when' code and it works great. But I am not sure how to use dynamic SQL... Could you please give a bit more detail?

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
update  TableX
set     TableX.A =  case when TableY.Ax <= TableY.Ay then TableY.Ax + TableY.Ay
                        else TableY.Ay + TableY.Ax
                    end,
        TableX.B = case when TableY.Bx <= TableY.By then TableY.Bx + TableY.By
                        else TableY.By + TableY.Bx
                    end,
        TableX.C = case when TableY.Cx <= TableY.Cy then TableY.Cx + TableY.Cy
                        else TableY.Cy + TableY.Cx
                    end
from    TableX 
inner join TableY on TableX.ID=TableY.ID
```

In general, read carefully about [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement and [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operator.

**Updated**, according to @Hong2020 comments:

You can use dynamic SQL to update columns in any combinations. For example, it can be a stored procedure (**Updated again at 2020 Jan 9**):

```
create procedure dbo.SP_UPDATE_COLS
    @Column     nvarchar(100),  --  column to be updated
    @xCol       nvarchar(100),
    @yCol       nvarchar(100)
as

    declare @SQL    nvarchar(max) = '
    update  TableX
    set     TableX.' + @Column + ' =  case when TableY.' + @xCol + ' <= TableY.' + @yCol + ' then ''^''+TableY.' + @xCol + ' + ''^'' + TableY.' + @yCol + '
                            else ''^'' + TableY.' + @yCol + ' + ''^'' + TableY.' + @xCol + '
                        end
    from    TableX 
    inner join TableY on TableX.ID=TableY.ID
    ';

    exec(@SQL);
    --select    @SQL;
go
```

Comment: Also many thanks for the reply, Makcnm. I have also been reading about creating procedure for the last two days. Will explore more once I get the EXEC query sorted and let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: Hi Makcnm, I have run the query you wrote and it created procedure successfully. However, when I tried to execute it, it give an error message 'String or binary data would be truncated' and the execute query I run is: execute dbo.SP_UPDATE_COLS A,Ax,Ay what have I done wrong please? thanks

Comment: I guess, it depends on type of columns A, Ax, Ay. What is their type?

Comment: For example, if A, Ax and Ay are VARCHAR(2). Ax and Ay contain values '11' and '12' respectively, then Ax+Ay is varchar(4) - this value can't be assigned to A, because A is VARCHAR(2).

Comment: Thanks Makcnm, I changed three nvarchar to 200, 100 and 100 then changed them all to max, but still got the same error message...:(

Comment: Can show your tables description? I mean columns A, Ax and Ay in tables `TableX` and `TableY`.

Comment: I am now trying to simplify the query, just declare two variables @x and @y, such as:
Declare @x varchar (20), @y varchar (20) 
set @x=table1.Ax set @y=table1.Ay 
update table2 set table2.A=
case when @x<=@y then @x+@y 
else @y+@x 
end 
from table1 inner join table2 
on table1.ID=table2.ID 

But it gives error message of line 2, "The multi-part identifier 'table1.Ax' (and 'table1.Ay') could not be bound."
What have I done wrong?

Comment: TableX contains about 40 columns Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy, Dx, Dy etc., each is 12 varchar when created, the last column is Delim which is 2 varchar; Table Y has half of the columns, each is 20...... I see, it should be 24?

Comment: It worked!...I nearly give up! Thank you so much! just one last thing, I forgot to say I need add a ^ in front of Ax and Ay, so it supposed to be ^Ax^Ay, now it won't let me...If I add a ' or " in front of ^, it won't recognize, says incorrect syntax. Suggestion please? Thanks

Comment: I updated the procedure according to your new requirements.

Comment: I see...Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

1. The simplest way to achieve the "Ax then Ay or Ay then Ax, whichever is smaller" is to use a CASE expression.

```
    CASE when @x < @y then @x + @y else @y + @x END
```

2. You cannot assign a column name to a variable and then run SQL that tells it to update the column named in that variable. This is simply not supported in SQL: you must ALWAYS know what columns you are updating at the time you write the statement. The closest equivalent is using dynamic SQL, which is almost always a bad idea.
3. Your code structure shows you are thinking "row by row" -- do this on the row, then that on the row, then the next thing on the row, and finally move to the next row. Efficient SQL is achieved when you think in sets. You should have *one* SQL statement, possibly with CTEs to determine individual results.

While I was trying to write the SQL that I would recommend, Максим Золотенко provided a full answer. I'm still posting this because I think the points I've raised are useful to think about.

Comment: Thank you Ross for your advice. I am so grateful for all the help here. If I define the column name for update, is it possible to use variable function for source column? For example: declare @x=update column A set A=case when @x>@y then @x+@y else @y+@x

Comment: Sorry I didn't finish the first comment: For example: Declare @x varchar (20), @y varchar (20)
set @x=table1.Ax
set @y=table1.Ay
update table2
set table2.A=case when @x<=@y then @x+@y 
else @y+@x
end
from table1
inner join table2
on table1.ID=table2.ID
But it gives error message "The multi-part identifier "set @x=table1.Ax" could not be bound.  I did use dbo for all tables but have removed then all but no use. Any suggestion please? thanks

Comment: "is it possible to use variable function for source column"? Nope, it is never possible to do this. You'll need Dynamic SQL if you really need to determine which column to update at runtime.

Comment: Sorry I may not explained myself well...I mean I can define the column for update at the beginning, as on the query I have update table 2 and set table2 column A to be updated. But can I use variable for source column (Ax and Ay from table 1)?

Comment: Oh sorry. The terrible formatting that StackOverflow does for comments made it very hard to read what you'd written. Assuming [this](https://pastebin.com/cDmCqE3t) is what you meant ... it's still not going to do what you think.  You seem to want @x to be some kind of reference to the Ax column in table1 ... that can't be done with SQL. But you could eliminate the variables completely like [this](https://pastebin.com/uS7B5Vwt).

Comment: Thank you, I understand now

Answer (score 0):

You can just update each column in a statement instead of using a function. Copy paste can make this really easy.

```
UPDATE dbo.X
SET x.A = CASE WHEN Ax > Ay THEN Ax+Ay ELSE Ay+Ax END,
x.B = CASE WHEN Bx > By THEN Bx+BY ELSE By+Bx END
FROM X
INNER JOIN Y
ON x.ID = Y.ID
```

If you want to be able to run this on various columns with the same pattern without adding `SET` statements to this update query, you will have to use dynamic sql since column names cannot be variables. Here is the dynamic sql.

````
DECLARE @columnPrefix VARCHAR(20) = 'A';

DECLARE @updateQuery VARCHAR(MAX) = 'UPDATE dbo.X  
SET x.' + @columnPrefix + '= CASE WHEN ' + @columnPrefix + 'x > ' + @columnPrefix + 'y THEN ' + @columnPrefix + 'x+' + @columnPrefix + 'y ELSE ' + @columnPrefix + 'y+' + @columnPrefix + 'x END
FROM X
INNER JOIN Y
ON x.ID = Y.ID';
EXEC(@updateQuery);```
````

Comment: Thanks Makcnm, Ross and Aliza, can you see my comment in answer section?

Comment: @Hong2020 I added some code that answers your new question

Comment: You **cannot** have `SET` twice in a single `UPDATE` statement. The second assignment should be just the assignment - **without** the `SET` keyword.....

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I have now understand the logic behind the dynamic SQL. However, when I run the query, it says the first line "String or binary data would be truncated." hence it will not run. The only thing I can found explanation online is that the value entered is more than what is defined which is certainly not correct as the column name has maximum 4 letters and even if I use one letter or change to NVARCHAR or change the number from 20 to max, it makes no difference, still give me the same error message. Please advise.

Comment: Hi Aliza, just like to let you know, after I altered the varchar number for destination columns as suggested by Marcnm, your query also worked brilliantly! Many thanks for all your help!